# Few questions on WCF sessions

Tags: wcf

Found few interview questions on WCF session, Can anyone help me answer these. I have gine through the msdn documentation for WCF, but still im not (100%) sure about answer to these questions

·         Why we need the sessions? 
·         Where session stores the session information? What is the general store for the WCF session?
·         What is it a correlation? What parameters are mandatory for the correlation?
·         What order are the delivered messages processed in during the session? 
·         Does the SessionMode.NotAllowed increase the performance?
·         How does a client start a session?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use sessions?  Only if you need to persist data between calls, or for some reason need to tie a client to a particular service instance (which is usually not a good idea).

In general, it's advised to think long and hard about your service before deciding to use sessions and durable sessions since doing so can have a big impact on performance.  Many times there are better ways to solve problems.

Here's an article all about instance management in WCF ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx)).  Hopefully it will answer most of your questions.

I strongly suggest reading chapter 4 in Juval Lowy's Programming WCF Services ([link](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805494/)) for more information - that chapter goes into great detail on instance management and should answer all of your questions.